# Actionscript Movieclip fade

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm struggling with something rather simple in flash at the moment.

Imagine you have two movieclips ontop of eachother. Both of these movieclips have identical movieclips within them.

If I fade out the top movieclip I expect to see no change at all, but for some reason I can see the fade happen.

It's like actionscript is fading out the sub movieclips independently.

Anyone know how to get around this? I don't want to be able to see any fade at all.

**Edit:**

People seem to be having trouble visualising what I'm having trouble with. Here's a really simple example in code:

```
var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
format.size = 100;
format.color = 0xFFFFFF;

// create a red square with text inside
var x:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
x.graphics.beginFill(0xCC0000);
x.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
x.graphics.endFill();
var x_txt:TextField = new TextField();
x_txt.text = "hello";
x_txt.width = 500;
x_txt.setTextFormat(format);
x.addChild(x_txt);
addChild(x);


// create a red square with text inside
var y:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
y.graphics.beginFill(0xCC0000);
y.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
y.graphics.endFill();
var y_txt:TextField = new TextField();
y_txt.text = "hello";
y_txt.width = 500;
y_txt.setTextFormat(format);
y.addChild(y_txt);
addChild(y);

y.alpha = 0.5;
```

As far as I can tell, it makes no sense that the text displayed should not be pure white.

Instead, it comes out as a faded white. http://www.mikeefranklin.co.uk/Test2.swf

**Edit 2:**

```
I've decided to grab the bitmap data and add that instead. it's not ideal, but does what I was looking for.

var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
format.size = 100;
format.color = 0xFFFFFF;


// create a red square with text inside
var x:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
x.graphics.beginFill(0xCC0000);
x.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
x.graphics.endFill();
var x_txt:TextField = new TextField();
x_txt.text = "hello";
x_txt.width = 500;
x_txt.setTextFormat(format);
x.addChild(x_txt);


var xbmpd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(x.width, x.height);
xbmpd.draw(x);
addChild(new Bitmap(xbmpd));


// create a red square with text inside
var y:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
y.graphics.beginFill(0xCC0000);
y.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
y.graphics.endFill();
var y_txt:TextField = new TextField();
y_txt.text = "hello";
y_txt.width = 500;
y_txt.setTextFormat(format);

y.addChild(y_txt);

var ybmpd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(y.width, y.height);
ybmpd.draw(y);
addChild(new Bitmap(ybmpd));


y.alpha = 0.5;
```

**Edit 3:**

Setting blendMode to BlendMode.Layer seems to do the job instead, which is nice.

Comment: Of course it does, remember that your second movieclip y has a red background too, and that red background is at 0.5 alpha, so it overlaps onto the first movieclip.

Comment: So if you set alpha on a movie clip, it alphas all the individual movieclips WITHIN that to 0.5? not just the entire thing?

Comment: The movieclip you're setting the alpha on is the container so if you set that alpha to 0.5, it'll fade whatever it displays by 0.5. The internal alphas are still 1 relative to that parent movieclip container. Hope that makes sense...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is that there are two objects in the MovieClip. You have to understand how flash handles alpha transparency for MCs. Each child of y has the aplha of 0.5. wich means you will see a little red through the hello of y. and that red is covering the hello of x.

you could set the visibility of the red shape in y to false. then you will not see the fade.

Answer (score 1):

<s>If you were only looking to have that top movie clip fade without the transparency layering on top of the bottom movieclip, you could just change the blendMode to Overlay before you apply the alpha.</s>

> y.blendMode = BlendMode.OVERLAY;
>   
> y.alpha = 0.5;

Nevermind, seems like you found it xD

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating two seperate movieclips or using the same reference twice? A movieclip can only have one parent, so if you do like this:

container.addChild(mc);
container.addChild(mc);

Only one movieclip will exist. That could explain why you see a fading, because there is no movieclip behind the movieclip you are fading.

Comment: No, they're separate instances of the movieclip.

Comment: Perhaps you are fading the parent movieclip instead? Have you tried putting the movieclips next to eachother to make sure that both are visible at once?

Comment: Here's an example of my problem: http://www.mikeefranklin.co.uk/test.fla   http://www.mikeefranklin.co.uk/test.swf

Comment: 1) Please post code, not files - much faster for people to help you if they do not have to open another program to see the code (in my case, I would have to open flash in vmware). 2) The url does not work

Comment: I've done that on the timeline as a clear example to the problem, so unable to do it as code. The link should now work. The .swf should make it clear enough.

Comment: From your swf, it seems the asset you're instantiating is looping a transition tween.
That does you no good if there's no code to stop the tween at the start or end.
Then again this is speculation since you've posted no code either....

Comment: Hi, yes - I'm tweening the top ones alpha to 0 and looping. In theory you should see no difference though, as the pixels should be identical on both the top and the bottom so you shouldnt be able to see any fade.

Comment: but if the asset you're creating automatically tweens itself when you create it, then the top and bottom will tween fade at the same time. Do you know if that timeline tween inside your asset has been stopped at the start?

Comment: asphere has a point there. You could check this by stopping one of the mc:s at creation with .gotoFrameAndStop() or whatever its called :)

Comment: Hi, I'm updating my original question with more info